# Show if $a \equiv b \pmod{m}$ then $ac \equiv bc\pmod{mc}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to give a **direct proof** using the definitions of mod m and congruence modulo m, ***without*** using any theorem involving mod or congruence.

if $a, b, c$ & $m$ are integers such that $m \geq 2$, $c > 0$ and $a \equiv b \pmod{m}$, then $ac \equiv bc\pmod{mc}$

Comment: What's your definition of congruence? In the common one it should follow from a simple multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a \equiv b \pmod{m}\iff b=a+km \implies cb=ca+kcm\implies ca \equiv cb \pmod{cm}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ m\mid n\, \Rightarrow\,  mc\mid nc.\ $ OP has $\ n = a-b$

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful.