# Show if $a \equiv b \pmod{m}$ then $ac \equiv bc\pmod{mc}$ without restrictions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For this question here:
[Show if $a \equiv b \pmod{m}$ then $ac \equiv bc\pmod{mc}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1996762/show-if-a-equiv-b-pmodm-then-ac-equiv-bc-pmodmc/4797987?noredirect=1#comment10203234_4797987)

Does $c$ need to be greater than $0$, for instance can c be negative?, what about $m$ being $2$ or greater? In the proof it does not appear …
Therefore, if these conditions are not given, is it invalid?

Comment: The definition of $a\equiv b\bmod m$ says $m\mid (b-a)$ for arbitrary integers $a,b,m$. But by convention we take $m$ positive. Therefore we want $m>0$ and $mc>0$, so $c>0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a\equiv b\pmod{m}$, it implies that $m\mid(a-b)$.
Since, $mc\mid(a-b)$ iff $m\mid(a-b)$, it must be true for all non-zero integer $c$. ($c$ cannot be $0$ since division by $0$ is absurd)
In conclusion, $c$ can be any non-zero integer.

Comment: For $c=0$: There are [some definitions for $\equiv \pmod 0$ as a relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/516251/89922). While division by $0$ is absurd, determining whether $ac-bc = 0$ is a multiple of $0$ is possible (and always true).

Answer (score 0):

$a \equiv b \pmod m \implies m|(a - b) \implies mk = a - b$

$ac - bc = c(a - b) = cmk \implies cm|(ac - bc)$

$\implies ac \equiv bc \pmod {mc}$